# Double click select does not consider - as a word in Windows 10 for onenote

Tags: windows-10, clipboard, onenote

when i double click on a word with special char "-"  in *OneNote* or xshell it does not copy entire word to clipboard. eg  double clicking on a word

```
                    ravi-test
```

mouse just copy word "ravi" to clipboard leaving behind "-test"

is there a way to configure clipboard setting in win 10 so that whole word  ravi-test is copied?

thanks

Comment: It's related to [OneNote's inability to double-click drag word select](https://onenote.uservoice.com/forums/327186-onenote-for-windows/suggestions/6234352-double-click-and-drag-to-select-multiple-words) sadly.  Been that way since at least 2016. :(

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately this feature is not available in OneNote, however it is possible to add it with AutoHotKey. The script that attempts to mimic this is as follows:

```
    ~LButton:: MouseGetPos x1,,win
If (A_TimeSincePriorHotkey<400) and (A_TimeSincePriorHotkey<>-1){

~LButton Up::
   SetTitleMatchMode, 2                     ; Checks for OneNote. You have to modify or
   If WinActive("OneNote") <> win           ; remove this tree lines to be able to
      Exit                                  ; work with another apps
   MouseGetPos x2
   If (x2 - x1) < -6{
        send {right}
        Send +{LButton} 
    }
   else If (x2 - x1) > 6 Or (A_TickCount - t) < 300
      Send +{LButton}
   t := A_TickCount
   return
}
Return
```

Thanks to: [This](https://www.autohotkey.com/boards/viewtopic.php?f=18&t=102500), [This](https://www.autohotkey.com/board/topic/56493-easiest-way-to-detect-double-clicks/) and [This](https://www.autohotkey.com/board/topic/71766-solved-left-drag-selectcopydouble-clickcopy/)

Basically, when you select a word and drag the mouse to the left or right, once you release the second click it will press Shift+Left Click (i.e. it will select everything up to where the mouse is)

You will not see the highlighted text in real time. To achieve this you can try a script that presses Ctrl+Shift+Right/Left Arrow (select text by words) depending on where the mouse is currently and taking as reference the position of the highlighted text, to obtain those coordinates see [this](https://www.autohotkey.com/board/topic/32778-get-pixel-location-of-selected-text/).

Update:
I do not recommend it has a few bugs:

- when selecting the tab it automatically double clicks
- when selecting text or paragraphs it selects everything
  Maybe somebody will improve this code